# Core Java How to convert 20 byte byte array to a string

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am getting input 20 byte . The charset used is UTF-8

when I convert it as string, I see 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

this is correct.

But when I convert it to string, I get a empty  value. I suspect charset as problem, but even after trying different charSets, I could not return the value '0'.

```
public String convertFromBytes(byte[] input) {
    System.out.println("BYTES ARE =="+ Hex.encodeHexString(input));
    System.out.println("VALUE IS "+ new String(input, this.charset));
    return new String(input, this.charset);
}
```

I tried changing charSet but not able to solve it, Any clues what I might be missing.

US-ASCII
ISO-8859-1
UTF-8
UTF-16BE
UTF-16LE
UTF-16

Comment: "But when I convert it to string, I get a empty value." - No, you almost certainly get U+0000 twenty times. If you've got a value of 0 for each byte, that's the correct result. It's not clear to me why you'd expect to get anything else - note that the character '0' is *not* encoded as a byte 0 in any encoding I'm aware of.

Comment: yes I get 20 empty spaces now. What you said is correct.

Comment: Well U+0000 isn't a space, but that's a different matter...

Answer (score 1):

*I have not tested the code.*

A I understand, you try to convert `{0x00, 0x00, 0x00...}` to `"000..."`, but you get nothing. Since the value of `'0'`, as a character is not `0` but (ASCII) `48`, this wont print anything. There is a difference between dumping a hex value, and interpreting an array of hexadecimals as a string with encoding.

Try with `{48, 48, 48...}`, the string will be `"000000.."`, but the hex writeline will produce `"48484848..."`, or something like that.

PS: The code for `'0'` is `48` **in base 10**.

**Edit:** It seems your string is not empty, just contains non-printable characters.

Comment: Since the input value is {0x00, 0x00, 0x00...   20 times}, I should return '0' back to the place where this method is called . Any idea how I can achieve that.

Comment: @user2604052: *Why* should you return "0"? That would be a very odd result if you're meant to be treating this as encoded text and decoding it.

Comment: The code for '0' if 48 with most if not all encodings. You get an empty value, because in memory the string "0" looks like `0x30 0x00`, the hex code for '0', and the terminating NULL character. You try to encode a series of terminating nulls. On solution is to check if the string is empty, then return "0".

Comment: @JonSkeet   Consider a situation where I have a map the return from this method is the value for the map.  In such a case, I should return 0 right, I cannot put key= x and value = 20 empty spaces to the map right.

Comment: @PnDChameleon: The OP doesn't actually have an empty string. They have a string consisting of U+0000 twenty times. That's not the same thing - Java strings aren't null-terminated, so it's just the Unicode NULL character...

Comment: @PnDChameleon   so that means that str.isEmpty() ? "0" : str; won't work right.

Comment: yeah, that wont work then. Btw I really dont understand what you want to accomplish

Comment: I know value is 0 before hand, but I have to check it programmatically.   I am getting a 20 byte bytearray from a source,  I have to check the content of this and enter to a map.So what happens now is, when I get the value the contents is U+0000....20 times. So map essentially <key, U+000000>. So while comparing I am expecting a 0, my comparison fails.   This is the problem I am facing.